# Why dml error logging ignored in remote db

Tags: oracle, error-handling, insert, dblink

I have that table - DIM_BP in 2 databases, with the same structure and data.

Those tables have PK on some columns.

There is an insert statement with dml error logging for catch the errors during the insert.

When I run the insert command from DB1 into DB2 with dblink - I got an error of PK unique constraint and the statement fail (dml error logging ignored).

But when I run in it from DB1 into DB1 (local) - there is no error.. and the error table filled with the errors..

example:

```
-- truncate table error table
truncate table DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV;
table DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV truncated.

-- truncate table in local DB
truncate table DWH.DIM_BP;
table DWH.DIM_BP truncated.

-- (log in to the remote server and) truncate the table
truncate table DWH.DIM_BP;
table DWH.DIM_BP truncated.

-- log to the local DB again

-- first insert into the remote
-- finisehd OK and commited
INSERT /*+ monitor */ INTO DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV
SELECT * FROM ...
LOG ERRORS INTO DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV.2019-04-16 16:05:58') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

130,091 rows inserted.

commit;

-- first insert into the local
-- finisehd OK and commited
INSERT /*+ monitor */ INTO DWH.DIM_BP
SELECT * FROM ...
LOG ERRORS INTO DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV.2019-04-16 16:05:58') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

130,091 rows inserted.

commit;

-- run the same insert again into the local table(130091)
INSERT /*+ monitor */ INTO DWH.DIM_BP
SELECT * FROM ...
LOG ERRORS INTO DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV.2019-04-16 16:05:58') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

0 rows inserted.

COMMIT;

select count(*) from dwh.ERR$_DWH_CONV;
result: 130091

-- run the same insert again into the REMOTE table(130091)
-- RAISED AN ERROR
INSERT /*+ monitor */ INTO DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV
SELECT * FROM ...
LOG ERRORS INTO DWH.ERR$_DWH_CONV ('DWH.DIM_BP@DWH_DEV.2019-04-16 16:05:58') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

SQL Error: ORA-00001: unique constraint - DWH.DIM_BP_PK

-- check again the error table
select count(*) from dwh.ERR$_DWH_CONV;
result: 130091 (no change)

this is the constraint:
CONSTRAINT "DIM_BP_PK" PRIMARY KEY... ENABLED;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported, to either a local or remote error logging table, but isn't mentioned in the docs still as far as I can tell. See MoS doc ID 1948989.1.

Comment: This is a bug. Thanks.